# Multi-level RecyclerView OnClick

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

[Multi-Level RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NooU.png)

I wanted to implement an onClick function into the Recyclerview, but I have no idea how to get through the first adapter [RecyclerView 1] from [RecyclerView 2].

Attempt: 
- Added onClick interface to RecyclerView 2 and implemented in RecyclerView1
- Added onClick interface to RecyclerView 1 and implemented in fragment

Result: 
- onClick listener reaches RecyclerView 1's implemented onClick

The idea is to handle these clicks in the fragment in which I have created, each of the boxes after the categories are images, how do i tackle this issue?